# vue devServer proxy is not working after build

Tags: javascript, vue.js, proxy

I am trying to call my API through proxy. It works fine locally. But while I build and upload to my server it does not work.

in my vue.config.js file :

```
devServer: {
proxy: {
  "^/rest": {
    target: 'https://v1.quant-ux.com',
    ws: true,
    changeOrigin: true,
    pathRewrite: {'^/rest' : '/rest'}
  },
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `devServer` only runs in local environments (on your machine during development). It's a separate process from your build, so you can't deploy a Vue app with a built-in proxy server.

Your options:

1. Rewrite your URLs to the proxy target (e.g., a build script/plugin).
2. Run your own proxy on the server (assuming you have control of it).